# Gaps appearing in results when converting CSV to points shapefile

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, csv

I'm trying to process a bunch of CSVs into point featureclass shapefiles in arcpy. The following is my code:

```
myCSVs = arcpy.ListFiles("*.csv") # Get all relevant CSV files

for i in myCSVs:
    arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(workspace + "//" + i,out_table + i[0:-4],'Longitude','Latitude','Elevation',arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
```

For what seems like most of my results, the product is complete with every row in the CSV file being represented by a point. But, some appear like this (Displayed in ENVI): [image]

Those squiggly areas are gaps. The CSVs have the same coordinates as the other CSV files, no data gaps. How can I figure out what's going on?

Comment: I've looked at the results for myCSVs. It is listing all of the files. I think the error is in the second part of the script, but I don't think it's an error in the script because many CSVs are processing properly. I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: What is the end product supposed to look like? Points will have gaps between them. It is not a polygon (continuous).

Comment: The idea is to convert the CSV to point featureclass and then to TIFF. Those gaps end up being gaps in the TIFF file. Those are gaps where points should exist (this image is zoomed out as it covers a large area)

Comment: I don't think anything is actually wrong. Some points just have coordinates that are further away from each other. Can you use the rasterize tool (vector to raster), set you parameters such as pixel size and see what you come out with?

Comment: Pixels that do not contain a point will be NA and should be blank/transparent. If you don't want that, then increase your pixel size. But be aware that other pixels could contain multiple points and it's value could be based on an average.

Comment: Can you share the csv file?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I was away.

In response to Zman3's comments, I have a list of identical datasets (all with the same point locations, just different additional columns) and sometimes all of the points are represented and sometimes they aren't. Sometimes I get those data gaps (that you see in the image) and sometimes I don't. I have checked all of the data sets that are giving me errors and the CSV files don't have any errors or gaps, but ArcGIS still produces these errors. I tried playing with the pixel size before, but that's not the issue.

Comment: At this point, I have found that using R gets all of the points vectorized without issue, so I will use that instead, but I would still like to know the issue with ArcGIS. Is this a bug in the 'CSV to Point' tool or may it be the processing power of my computer...?